# Merging datasets with "dataframe", colnames are changing from ; to., why?

Tags: r

I discovered something in my dataset and I dont understand why it happends. Here i have reproduced the datatset. When I combine two dataframe to one the ; are changing to a dot".", but it only happens when I do df <- data.frame(dfmeta,dd), not if I do df <- cbind(dfmeta,dd). What (and why) is happening when I do data.frame?
Many thanks for suggestions!

```
 a <- c("Bacteria;p","Bacteria;p","Bacteria;p")
b <- c("Bacteroidetes;c",   "Firmicutes;c", "Bacteroidetes;c")
c <- c("Bacteroidia;o", "Clostridia;o", "Bacteroidia;o")
otu <- data.frame(a,b,c)


name <- apply(otu,1,function(x) paste(x, collapse = ' '))
a <- data.frame(name)
q1<- c(2,3,4)
q2<- c(5,6,7)
q3<- c(2,6,9)
dd<- data.frame(q1,q2,q3)
colnames(dd)<- name
dd
  Bacteria;p Bacteroidetes;c Bacteroidia;o Bacteria;p Firmicutes;c Clostridia;o
1                                        2                                    5
2                                        3                                    6
3                                        4                                    7
  Bacteria;p Bacteroidetes;c Bacteroidia;o
1                                        2
2                                        6
3                                        9
b.t <- c(1:3)
bb <- LETTERS[1:3]
dfmeta <- data.frame(b.t,bb)
df <- data.frame(dfmeta,dd)
df
b.t bb Bacteria.p.Bacteroidetes.c.Bacteroidia.o Bacteria.p.Firmicutes.c.Clostridia.o
1   1  A                                        2                                    5
2   2  B                                        3                                    6
3   3  C                                        4                                    7
  Bacteria.p.Bacteroidetes.c.Bacteroidia.o.1
1                                          2
2                                          6
3                                          9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check `?data.frame` function it has got `check.names` argument which is set to `TRUE` by default.

> check.names
> logical. If TRUE then the names of the variables in the data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names and are not duplicated. If necessary they are adjusted (by make.names) so that they are.

which means that it tries to create a syntactically valid column names for the data that you have passed.

What is a syntactically valid name is explained in `?make.names`

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the reserved words. The character "X" is prepended if necessary. All invalid characters are translated to "."

So all the column names that have spaces or semi-colon are replaced with dot. `cbind` doesn't have such argument so it allows column names that are syntactically invalid.

If you want `data.frame` to allow that as well turn off `check.names`.

```
data.frame(dfmeta,dd, check.names = FALSE)

#  b.t bb Bacteria;p Bacteroidetes;c Bacteroidia;o Bacteria;p Firmicutes;c Clostridia;o
#1   1  A                                        2                                    5
#2   2  B                                        3                                    6
#3   3  C                                        4                                    7
#  Bacteria;p Bacteroidetes;c Bacteroidia;o
#1                                        2
#2                                        6
#3                                        9
```